# Install Ubuntu issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, crash

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.4 LTS alongside my windows 10 (dual boot), on my asus x541u - Notebook PC (not X541U(X)) (no graphics card other then my CPU on board graphics).  When I boot from my LiveUSB (hash checksum checks out), I see many PCIe bus errors ([image: check picture]) around the time I am choosing the Keyboard settings (so shortly after I start the process), I have let it run for 1 hour and it didn't change anything, it just shows the same error over and over again, and I can't do anything.

Keep in mind this computer had Ubuntu already in the past.

I have check online for fix, but never found someone that had this issue while installing Ubuntu.

sorry for the picture quality, was taken from my phone.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you have the X541UJ https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/X541UJ/HelpDesk/HelpDesk/ https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X541UAK/0409_E11966_X441_X541_V2_A.pdf or the X541UA https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/X541UA/HelpDesk/HelpDesk/ https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X541SA/0409_E11304_X441_X541_A.pdf

Comment: I have this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZYOAxA487U
couldn't find it in Asus laptop list

Comment: Please turn it over and look for the serial number sticker. On there you will also find the real model number, not whatever Asus marketing decided to stamp on the lid, bezel, or keyboard surround. Please click on [edit] and put that information in the original post; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].